Spark Code Completion in Visual Studio Code
I am trying to use Visual Studio Code for Spark development.
My PySpark code all runs fine, but there is no code completion/hints.
How can I add these features for VS Code?
I have the Python and Pylance extensions installed.
In PyCharm this all work perfectly as expected.

do you have any error when you import the packages ?

I don't get any error. Code all runs without issue. Just no code hints.

As mentioned in doc, you need to install and set up the Databricks extension for Visual Studio Code.
To enable IntelliSense (also known as code completion) in the Visual Studio Code code editor for PySpark, Databricks Utilities, and related globals such as spark and dbutils, do the following with your code project opened:

On the Command Palette (View > Command Palette), type >Databricks:
Configure autocomplete for Databricks globals and press Enter.
Follow the on-screen prompts to allow the Databricks extension for
Visual Studio Code to install PySpark for your project, and to add
or modify the __builtins__.pyi file for your project to enable
Databricks Utilities.


I am not using databricks. I want to run code on my laptop.

Or you could try to add the path of pyspark to the settings.json. It should look like:   "python.analysis.extraPaths": [     "/path/to/your/pyspark"   ]

I've tried this. It doesn't seem to make any difference.

The solution I found was to use the Jedi language server:-
"python.languageServer": "Jedi"
For Jupyter notebook you also need to set:-
"jupyter.enableExtendedPythonKernelCompletions": true

Hi Bob, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
